# Problem : Need to make COM InterOp at runtime using reflections Passing Pointers as parameters?

Tags: c++, reflection, dynamic, .net-4.0, com-interop

I need to make COM IntetrOp at runtime using reflections. My native COM Object's exposed methods have some parameters as pointers (DWORD*) and some double pointers (DWORD**) and some are user defined types(e.g SomeUDTType objSmeUDTType) and vice versa its pointer(i.e. SomeUDTType *pSomeUDTType).

Now for dynamic method invocation, we have single option for passing parameters as array of object i.e object[] and filling this array statically.

But I need to pass pointers and references and pointers to pointers. For now how can I be able to populate object array as mixed data of simple data types, pointers or references and pointers to pointers.

Working Example:

**Native COM exposed method :**

```
STDMETHODIMP MyCallableMethod(DWORD *value_1,BSTR *bstrName,WESContext **a_wesContext)
```

**Translated by tlbimp.exe (COMInterop)**

```
UDTINIDLLib.IRuntimeCalling.MyCallableMethod(ref uint, ref string, System.IntPtr)
```

Now calling these methods at runtime using reflection at runtime,

See here :

```
       Assembly asembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("E:\\UDTInIDL\\Debug\\UDTINIDLLib.dll");
        Type[] types = asembly.GetTypes();


        Type type = null;
        //foreach (Type oType in types)
        {
            try
            {
                type = asembly.GetType("UDTINIDLLib.RuntimeCallingClass");

            }
            catch (TypeLoadException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            object parameters = new object[3];

            Type CustomType = asembly.GetType("UDTINIDLLib.WESContext");
            object oCustomType = Activator.CreateInstance(CustomType);
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = CustomType.GetField("MachineName",          BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

            string MachineName = "ss01-cpu-102";
            string MachineIp = "127.0.0.1";
            string Certificate = "UK/78T";

            fieldInfo.SetValue(oCustomType, MachineName);
            fieldInfo.SetValue(oCustomType, MachineIp);
            fieldInfo.SetValue(oCustomType, Certificate);


            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            MethodInfo mInfo = type.GetMethod("MyCallableMethod");
            int lengthOfParams = mInfo.GetParameters().Length;
            ParameterInfo [] oParamInfos = mInfo.GetParameters();



           object[] a_params = new object[lengthOfParams];

            int ValueType = 0;

            for(int iCount = 0; iCount<lengthOfParams; iCount++)
            {
                a_params[iCount] = ???; //Now here this array should be populated with corresponding pointers and other objects (i.e WESContext's obj)
            }

            mInfo.Invoke(obj,  a_params);
```

Hope code will clarifies ...If any any confusion do let me know I'll edit my question accordingly.

I am stuck here , I'll be obliged if you help me out.(I am confused about "dynamic" keyword might hope it solves the problem)

Is there any need to generate C++/CLI wrappers? and if in which context?
Regards
Usman

Comment: I seriously doubt you can make this work.  This COM server doesn't appear to be using Automation compatible argument types.  Those pointers actually look like arrays.  Make it work with the interop library first.  If that doesn't work then you'll have to write a C++/CLI wrapper for it.

Comment: These are just simple pointers. pointers to BSTRS and some DWORD. BSTR pointer points to just BSTRs and DWORDS have some addresses of DWORDS.
Problem is not here whether they are arrays or simple pointers, problem is to just make the call accordingly to method using InterOp while mapping data to corresponding BSTR pointer and DWORD pointer as its call is expected in normal condition..

I am using Interop library . used here tlbimp.exe to convert it to managed .NET object and then applying reflections on it. This is RCW(Runtime callable wrapper) which transfers calls to native COM world.

Comment: it's a good question though: did you try calling your COM API _without_ reflection (i.e. via a plain call to `MyCallableMethod` in code)? Did it work? If it doesn't, you should focus first on getting that work, and leave Reflection for later.

Comment: It works fine with plain calling.....
no problem for ref..
i declared ordinary uint  and passed as ref it works..

Answer (score 0):

Just put the *values* of your arguments directly into the array. For `out`/`ref` parameters, the corresponding elements of the array will be replaced by new values returned by the function.

For the double pointer, by far the easiest approach is to use `/unsafe` and unmanaged pointers, like so (assuming the parameter is used by the method to return a value):

```
 WESContext* pWesContext; // the returned pointer will end up here
 IntPtr ppWesContext = (IntPtr)&pWesContext;

 // direct call
 MyCallableMethod(..., ppWesContext);

 // reflection
 a_params[3] = ppWesContext;
 mInfo.Invoke(obj, a_params);
```

After you'll get the pointer to struct in `pWesContext`, you can use `->` to access the members in C#. I'm not sure what memory management rules for your API are, though; it may be that you will, eventually, need to free that struct, but how exactly to do that should be described by the documentation of the API you're trying to call.

Comment: It generates runtime exception : 


Object of type 'System.Int32' cannot be converted to type 'System.UInt32&'.

Comment: That's because it expects an `uint`, and you gave it an `int`. If you used a literal (e.g. 123), then suffix it with "u": `123u`. If you used a value of some computation, then explicitly cast it to `uint`.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to pass pointers adn references of User defined types e.g in above case SomeUDT* pSomeUDT.? In .NET everything is reference. But when I put oCustomType in one of params i.e in params[3] . It generates the runtime exception : **Target Invocation Method was unhandeled  : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.**

Comment: I already explained how references are handled in Reflection. There really isn't anything more to it - CLR references aren't first-class, and cannot be put as values into an array. The best you can get is the approach I've described, where you put in boxed values, and then Reflection passes a reference to each box to the actual code. Pointers are not relevant here because your method declaration doesn't have any pointers (and refs and pointers are different types).

Comment: As for your exception, it simply indicates that the method itself threw an exception once invoked. To find out the actual exception that it threw, you'll have to look at `InnerException` property of the `TargetInvocationException` that you've got. Please post the message you get from there, as well as the code that gives you that (just update the question), and we'll go from there.

Comment: Thanks Pavel : This is working almost. But only one problem left with double pointer(  I have edited the question at top. ) In this case it is expecting double pointer(** for WESContext) and translated Interop is System.IntPtr. So Now how to tackle this one as well?

Comment: ..One thing it generates tlbimp warning while generating managed tlb:  TlbImp : warning TI3015 : At least one of the arguments for 'UDTINIDLLib.RuntimeCallingClass.MyCallableMethod' cannot be marshaled by the runtime marshaler.  Such arguments will therefore be passed as a pointer and may require unsafe code to manipulate.

Comment: @Hassan: I've edited the answer to include info on double pointer, have a look.

Comment: Thanks Pavel for your continuous cooperation: But again WESContext is the type which's not included in current assembly rather it exists in other assembly which just produced after interop(produced by tlbim.exe) . It should work in any case. But while I create its pointer (*) in unsafe tag , it says that **"Error: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type ('UDTINIDLLib.WESContext')**

Comment: That is quite unfortunate - it seems that your COM struct has some fields of pointer-to-interface type, and, in combination with a double-pointer, it makes tlbimp produce a declaration that is, effectively, unusable. One option I see here is to manually tweak the interop assembly - if you change the type of last argument to `ref WESContext[]` (i.e. array passed by reference), that should match the level of indirection described by two pointers in COM. You'll then have to pass it a single-element array, and will receive the value in that first element.

Comment: To do so, you can decompile the interop assembly to IL using `ildasm.exe /out`, then find the declaration of your method by name, and tweak the type of the last argument - it will be `native int` originally (this corresponds to `IntPtr`), and you will need to replace that with `valuetype UDTINIDLLib.WESContext[]&`. Then recompile the modified IL with `ilasm.exe`. If that all sounds like too much trouble, it's because it might well be - if you have more than one method like that (with double pointers to structs), C++/CLI might be an easier route to take.